# How to trigger a custom function module on posting in MIRO?

Tags: abap

Can anyone help me with triggering or running my function module when someone posts invoice in MIRO or FB60.
      I tried with tracing the event, but there is no FM is created in default. So I am unable to get the event details. Please help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `EXIT_SAPLMRMP_004` for validation before posting:

1. Open `EXIT_SAPLMRMP_004` FM in SE37
2. There you'll find Z include which you should create.
3. In the created include place your FM.

Voila!